# Vue | How to import a stylesheet from a specific NPM package?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to load [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). This package is installed using the command `npm install --save animate.css`. Now, what is the best way to import it inside the project?

I have stumbled upon some solutions asking to copy the file inside the static folder and load it from there. But I would rather not to as we lose all the benefits of NPM if we move it from its package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want animate.css globally in your application

In your **webpack**

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: "css-loader" }
  ]
}
```

in yout **main.js**

```
import 'animate.css/animate.min.css'
```

Answer (score 4):

What I did with similar scenario in my project is used [src imports](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#src-imports).

In your **App.vue** component add two style tags , one for global styles as **App.vue**  is the entry point and other for scoped styles if you have any with the scoped attribute.

```
<style src="animate.css/animate.min.css">
    /* global styles */
</style> 

<style scoped>
    /* local styles */
</style>
```